Can I Prove Monotonicity of Allocations to the Rust Borrow Checker
I have the following code which does not compile:
// TODO: Return Result, remove `.expect`s
fn to_blender_subfile<'a>(
    filepath: &str,
    transform: Transform,
    visited_file_cache: &'a mut HashMap<&'a str, Vec<Command>>,
    blender: &mut Blender,
) {
    // TODO: Support colors and backface culling

    let commands = visited_file_cache.get(filepath).unwrap();
    // "unwrap" is enforced by the wrapper function

    for command in commands.iter() {
        if let Command::Subfile { filepath, .. } = command {
            if !visited_file_cache.contains_key(filepath.as_str()) {
                let mut file = std::fs::File::open(filepath).expect("Failed to open file");

                let mut file_contents = String::new();

                let contents_len = file
                   .read_to_string(&mut file_contents)
                   .expect("Failed to read file into buffer");

                assert_eq!(contents_len, file_contents.len()); // TODO: Check this


                // "parse_file" is defined elsewhere
                let commands = parse_file(&file_contents);

                if let Some(_) = visited_file_cache.insert(filepath.as_str(), commands) {
                    std::unreachable!();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ... rest of function
}

The error I get from rustc is:
cannot borrow `*visited_file_cache` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable 

referring to the fact that I both do visited_file_cache.insert(filepath.as_str(), commands) and let commands = visited_file_cache.get(filepath).unwrap(); while claiming visited_file_cache: &'a mut HashMap<&'a str, Vec<Command>>.
My understanding of what's going on, at least at a high level, is that the borrow checker is protecting me from mutating visited_file_cache while also referring to its values for its keys, since in general its keys may survive its values which can lead to dangling pointers.
This is all well and good, however by the nature of the code, if a key-value pair has been inserted into visited_file_cache it cannot be removed (i.e. it lives at least as long as the hashmap itself). I understand that the compiler cannot use this information, hence why it complains, but is there a way to express to the compiler that a region grows monotonically? I could then tell the compiler that visited_file_cache is backed by a monotonic allocator and its insert method is nondestructive, thus getting rid of the above error.
Can the compiler understand such structures, or are there predefined structures in the standard library that enforce the above behavior while using unsafe?
I am aware that I can trivially circumvent this issue by copying strings and making the keys of visited_file_cache owned, and I'm pretty sure I could also use reference counting. However, I don't think the infrastructure for either of those two solutions is necessary for my use case.
N.B. I am new to Rust (haven't looked the Rust Book yet, though I have looked at the Rustonomicon), but I have a C and Haskell background.

Missing types makes it hard to verify, but &'a mut T<'a> is almost always wrong. Your visited_file_cache looks like this, so you may be running into Why does this mutable borrow live beyond its scope? Try using different lifetimes for the keys and outer reference (or in this case you could probably just omit 'a altogether and the compiler will infer separate lifetimes as long as there's nothing else tied to 'a).

On second thought, what I mentioned is a problem but that won't make your code work.  You can't insert while an outstanding reference into the map still exists. The compiler is saving you from invalidating your commands. I don't think your "monotonic allocator" fixes anything; I'm not positive the current implementation of the standard HashMap, but I believe an insert may trigger a re-allocation and move existing key/values.

@kmdreko Why wouldn't it? With my version of a monotonic hash map, insert would not trigger a reallocation. insert would be "nondestructive" as I say in my question. As soon as you insert a key-value pair, that pair will not change throughout the entire duration of the enclosing hash map's lifetime.

@kmdreko Practically-speaking, the memory backing the hash map need not be contiguous between pairs (or really each component of the pair). Therefore such an allocator could be implemented as an unrolled linked list.

Rusts current hashtable implementation is based on hashbrown, which stores the entire hashtable in a single block of memory. If the number of inserts gets beyond the size of that block then it will need to move the existing pairs to a new larger block, breaking the references.

@user1937198 I recognize that, hence my question of how to circumvent this using a monotonic allocator as described above...

@WilliamRyman Not in std. You'd need something completely different from the std library hashmap. Because the problem is not the allocator, but the way std::collections::HashMap uses the allocator.

But even if you fixed that, you'd run into issues on the lifetime of the filepaths as keys. You likely need to switch to using owned String for that. The simplest way to resolve this is probably to build a new hashmap of additions, and then merge that into the existing map.

@user1937198 Is there really no better way to do this? What I want seems pretty basic. I'm surprised there's no pre-built solution for this.

@WilliamRyman Doing what you propose involves a relatively complicated API that is really only suitable for exactly one thing (building up collections), where the standard hashmap is optimized for ease in the common case (pushig things in and out, not maintaining references). Another cheap way out would be to assert that the Commands Vec is immutable and put it in an Rc. Allowing you to release the borrow on the hashtable entry before the loop.

If you want to just remove the reference counting, there's elsa::FrozenMap. Instead of a linked list, it mandates that each item is a pointer (e.g. Box), to which you only ever get a reference to its contents.

@drewtato Thanks, that's almost exactly what I was looking for in terms of API.

@user1937198 I don't see how the API would be complicated, it's essentially exactly the same as the code I have above except that it would just work... Also, despite what I propose being "suitable for exactly one thing" that thing is common and increasingly widespread. E.g. look at the gaming industry and their arena allocators.

Arena allocators are different because they are allocators. Put an arena allocator behind the hashbrown hashmap and it wouldn't fix the problem, because it would still move the pairs to a new contiguous block. The only way to 'solve' this in the allocator is for the allocator to allow guaranteed extending of existing blocks. Something that as far as I'm aware is impossible in practice. (An arena allocator only solves this if you only use it for this one thing, and pre-allocate for maximum possible size, if you can accept that just use a fixed capacity hashmap crate)

The guarentees you want has to be implemented in the hashmap, with support for non-contiguous allocation, which significantly complicates querying, before you even allow the design to handle safely failing in the case of attempting to use the same bucket twice, because their is no way in the rust typesystem to prove two values are not equal.

@user1937198 I'm not knowledgeable about hashbrown hashmaps, but I definitely see how contiguity could affect the algorithm. However the HashMap could simply be parameterized by an allocation type and the implementor could just statically dispatch on the type (I'm not actually sure how to do this in Rust, but I'm pretty sure it would look like HashMap<K, V, AllocationType::XX>) and implement different algorithms for different allocation types. This way, you won't have to pay for the cost of a potentially less efficient algorithm if you don't use it.

@user1937198
And BTW, my suggestion of using an unrolled linked list was just an implementation suggestion. The FrozenMap suggested above fits my definition of "monotonic" allocations as do immutable and "frozen" (I just discovered this term) data structures in general. The FrozenMap should work well with the hashbrown algorithm, and I'm sure this is why this method of implementation was chosen over mine.

@user1937198 Also I apologize for my abuse of the term "allocator". When I talk about different allocators, I'm talking about different patterns of allocation (not different methods of allocation), which (I'm sure) is what is meant by Rust's term of art.
Sorry for my belated response, I'm watching the US presidential debate right now.

@user1937198 "their is no way in the rust typesystem to prove two values are not equal," Yes, I agree, this is by far the hardest part of implementing a monotonic hashmap (but not monotonic allocations in general).
I'm not sure if this entirely aligns with the ethos of Rust (I don't think it would fit std), but this doesn't need to be enforced statically, a panic in debug mode might suffice. Also, this is just an issue with hashmaps, and does not respond to "Can I Prove Monotonicity of Allocations" in general.

@user1937198 Actually, after looking it up it appears std can indeed panic. But such a hash map wouldn’t work with no_panic.

@WilliamRyman This isn't something you can easily do with generics (the static dispatch mechanism you propose) because making what you propose work in Rust requires that mutating methods take a shared reference (& instead of &mut), which is what elsa::FrozenMap does, for example. You can't parameterize on whether a reference is shared or exclusive, not in a way that wouldn't horribly pollute the API, anyway. (There might be some tricks you can do with associated types, but it definitely seems like something niche enough to warrant its own proper type.)

@WilliamRyman In other words, having the map's insert method take &self or &mut self depending on some generic type is, as I understand it, not possible if you want to keep method syntax (map.insert(...)). You could have multiple impl blocks potentially, one with the &self version and one with the &mut self version, but only if you can convince the compiler that the impls can't both exist at the same time, and proving that impls are disjoint to the compiler is not always easy.

@cdhowie Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the response.

Step 1 of asking a question on SO: provide a reproducible example that people can play with.

First of all, if you only want the code to compile, then indeed you can relatively easily get there with a bit of cloning & owned keys: see the playground.
It is a bit boring, though, isn't it?
So, what do we need to be able to iterate & refer to the key & values of a map while modifying the map?
Leak it, leak it, leak it!
(Not be mistaken with "lick it, lick it, lick it!", no geologist was hurt in the making of this answer)
In Rust, it's safe to leak. In fact, there's an explicit function to do so. So we're going to leak all things:

The keys will be &'static str.
The commands will be &'static [Command].

Leaking a String can be achieved by going:
let filename: Box<str> = _string_;
let filename = Box::leak(filename);

And leaking a slice can be achieved by going:
let commands: Box<[Command]> = _vec_;
let commands = Box::leak(commands);

And that's it. We can now have a HashMap<&'static str, &'static [Command]> where filepath: &'static str in Command::Subfile and we're good to go.
Tweak it.
Leaking is safe, so it's cool, but... it doesn't really lend itself to repetition. So we need another option.
Another option would be for the map to guarantee that inserted keys & values will (1) not be moved and (2) not be mutated (while shared).
What's pretty cool about Rust is that you can, in fact, expressed such invariants (shared vs not-shared) at the type-level, so we get:
impl<K, V> PushMap<K, V> {
    //  Only reads & `insert_if_new` are possible for the duration of the borrow.
    fn get(&self, key: &K) -> Option<&V>;

    //  Returns `value` if the key is already present in the map.
    //
    //  This is unlike `insert` (which returns the previous value), hence the
    //  the different name.
    fn insert_if_new(&self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<(K, V)>;

    //  Mirror API of standard HashMap.
    fn get_mut(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<&mut V>;
    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V>;
    fn remove(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<V>;
}

The use of insert_new does require internal mutability. At the bottom this means UnsafeCell, and the Cell and RefCell wrappers won't cut it here, so we'll need to make our own.
This also means that it will NOT be possible to shared &PushMap across multiple threads (while it's possible with &HashMap) unless we also make it a concurrent map. It's a trade-off.
The exact implementation is left as an exercise to the reader. From the literature, a typical hash table implementation, with linked-lists as buckets, will fit the bill, although there's overhead in using linked-lists. Otherwise, an implementation atop the Jagged Array concept is also possible, see the jagged repository for an example.
